# Examples for these inference rules?

Tags: proof-explanation, natural-deduction

Upon reading the part `1.4.1 Logical Deductions` of the book [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/readings/MIT6_042JS15_textbook.pdf), I found the inference rules vaguely understood because only their notations are shown without concrete examples and I'm not sure if the examples I come up with by myself are legit or good enough. What are some typical examples for the following rules?

Rule 1.

> Modus Ponens: $\frac{P,\space\space P\space IMPLIES\space\space Q} Q$

Rule 2.

> $\frac{P\space\space IMPLIES\space\space Q,\space\space Q\space\space IMPLIES\space\space R} {P\space\space IMPLIES\space\space R}$

Rule 3.

> $\frac{NOT(P)\space\space IMPLIES\space\space NOT(Q)} {Q\space\space IMPLIES\space\space P}$

Non-rule.

> $\frac{NOT(P)\space\space IMPLIES\space\space NOT(Q)} {P\space\space IMPLIES\space\space Q}$

Comment: They are general, i.e. "recipies" applicable to every inference.

Comment: See e.g. P.Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&pg=PA1).

Comment: They are used in many many contexts: if it rains, then the ground is wet; but it is raining; therefore, the ground is wet (*Modus Ponens*). And: if the gorund is not wet, then it does not rain; therefore, if it rains, then the ground is wet (Rule 3).